# every php page creates own session

Tags: php, session

Checked all over the web and tried all possible solutions written about problems with sessions.

I have 3 pages: the 1st page reads some data from redirected form and stores 4 variables in session. Here is first session id generated and if I check print_r($_SESSION) all is ok.

The form from this page on submission goes to 2nd page where data is stored in mysql database (no session manipulation here), and then "meta" redirects to 3rd page.

Here I try to read variables from session, but instead a new session is generated.
If I look in my server tmp dir both sessions are here.

Why is new session generated instead of reading from first session?

- tried page encoding: ANSI, UTF-8 w BOM, UTF-8 wo BOM
- tried script that was written in php.net session manual

Any other ideas?

---

Code is simple session like this:

**1st php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

**2nd page tried**

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

output is `Array{ id -> }` so only empty variable

**3rd page**

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
echo $id;
```

and output is ''

Comment: Post your code. We can't help blind!

Comment: Check that the session cookie is propagating properly, and staying constant between each page request. If the session ID in the cookie changes, you'll be getting a new session each time. As well, ensure that all of your pages are doing session_start().

Comment: If "no session manipulation" on page 2 means that you're not calling `session_start()` - there's your problem.

Comment: Tnx all for reply. Polynominal: code is simple session like this: 1st php: session_start(); $_SESSION['id'] = $id; 2nd page tried session_start(); print_r($_SESSION) -> output is Array{ id -> } so only empty variable, 3rd page session_start(); $id = $_SESSION['id']; echo $id; and output is ''

Comment: I added the (formatted) code from your comment to the post. Remember that it is better to edit your post, especially when adding important details such as code snippets.

Comment: @psychoP: now, what is $id in the first page? And why would you set `$_SESSION['id']` manually? Finally, if you **really** need to manipulate the session id use the [session_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) function that PHP provides.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you set the $_SESSION['id'] empty with

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

cause $id is empty in your Script. Remove this line.

Comment: This is not it. In my real code I put inside session 14 variables and all are empty and id is not session id but some id of product that is read from user. Tried this exact code on some other server and all is ok. This server doesn't report any errors jst doesn't work. Tested here some other code with only 2 pages and that code works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a while and had a very hard time figuring it out. My problem was that I had the site working for a while with the sessions working right, and then all of the sudden everything broke.

Apparently, your session_save_path(), for me it was /var/lib/php5/, needs to have 777 chmod permissions. I accidentally changed it, breaking sessions completely.

To fix, just do `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php5/` (or whatever your session_save_path() is) on linux.

However issues with sessions are very strange and can be caused by a myriad of reasons...